# can't set iPhone 6+ headphones to max or full volume when playing music

Tags: audio, iphone, headphones, sound-volume, ear-phones

When I'm playing music in Spotify or any app with Apple earphones or auxiliary cable in my car, I can't turn music up to full volume. It goes as far as yellow indicator and 'High Volume' but won't go into the red. I wanna go up to 11 baby! Strange thing is it used to work a month ago, it used to go to the red. I didn't upgrade iOS or anything, I'm on jailbroken 8.1.1. I also have volume limit turned off in Music settings. I checked the earphone jack for lint and it seems clean.

I've Googled for days here and at a loss. Unless I'm using the Googles wrong, it seems I'm in the minority with this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any jailbreak-apps that could do this maybe?

Comment: @KevinGrabher you were right, it was the Activator tweak from ryan petrich

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was the jailbreak Activator tweak from Ryan Petrich. When I uninstalled it, I can go to full volume again.